# How to call Google Apps Script API by a service account

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api, service-accounts, google-directory-api, google-apps-script-api

I'd like to use a service account to access Google Spreadsheet via Google Apps Script API.

But now the Apps Script API doesn't seem to work with service accounts according to the following document.

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/api/concepts

Can I use a service account for DriveAPI,Admin DirectoryAPI, and Admin SDK?

Answer (score 0):

I think you may be confusing the Google Sheets API, or any other method to call a spreadsheet, with the Google Apps Script API. According to the [Documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/api/reference/rest), based on the methods listed there, the Google Apps Script API would work only for project management and deployments.

The warning related to the service accounts would only apply to these methods. Other ways to work with spreadsheets would definitely work with service accounts.